# Accidentlly changed permissions to system only with ownership to system in regedit

Tags: windows, permissions, registry, system, regedit

Actually I was trying to make changes in Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies of registry editor and changing permissions of admin and system to full control, other users as read only with ownership to admin.Unfortunately I did All users except SYSTEM as read only and ownership to SYSTEM. Now whatever I try to change, an alert box appear as "Couldn't Save change in policies---   Access Denied". So is there any way to change the ownership and permissions to admin.

I have asked in microsoft community, but a person said that I have to Reboot my PC to factory reset, which I don't want to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps try the following:

- Download https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec
- Run `psexec -i -s c:\windows\regedit.exe` as Admin
- Hope the best ;)